# flutter Websocket channel streams the same value over and over again

Tags: flutter, websocket, stream, repeat

Hey so on my backend everything works fine, a single message is sent, stored and etc. However on my frontend when sending a message to websocket channel, the value gets repeated and displayed multiple times.

Here is the code:

```
channel = IOWebSocketChannel.connect(
          Uri.parse('ws://10.0.2.2:8000/ws/chat/${widget.roomData.id}/'), headers: blablabla);
```

On send:

```
FloatingActionButton(
                    onPressed: () => {
                      channel.sink.add(
                          jsonEncode(
                              {
                                "context": _inputTextController.text,
                                "author_id": profileId,
                              }
                          )
                      ),
                      _inputTextController.text = ""
                    },
```

And here it all goes wrong

```
 Widget _chatBody() {
    return StreamBuilder<dynamic>(
        stream: channel.stream,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            if (ConnectionState.active == snapshot.connectionState) {
              GroupChatMessage _groupMessage = GroupChatMessage.fromJson(
                  jsonDecode(snapshot.data), profileId
              );
              print("still here?");
              messages.add(_groupMessage);
            }
          }
```

it prints `still here` from 3 to 6 times for every single text I send...
Any help please?